# what is difference between creating webservice in http and https

Tags: http, rest, jakarta-ee, https, jersey

I am working on creating rest service in java using Jersey. I am new at this, so I am a bit confused about what is the difference between creating services in http and https.

Do we need to take care of creating services. Please guide properly.

Tutorial I followed for creating service is [Click here for tutorial link](http://www.vogella.com/articles/REST/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

To you as an application developer, there is no difference. You simply deploy a web app (war file) to a servlet container.

If this server accepts http and/or https connections is up to the server's setup. What you can (and maybe should) do is that you refuse to work on an insecure (http) channel and enforce using SSL (https).